# With Entity Framework "Code First", how can I set a Boolean if the ID is in another table?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Say I have the following entities:

```
[Table("ReferenceManual.Origin")]
public partial class Origin
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int OriginId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string OriginName { get; set; }
}


[Table("ReferenceManual.NonAirportOrigin")]
public class NonAirportOrigin
{
    [Key]
    [Column("NonAirportOrigin")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int NonAirportOriginId { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to not have the 'NonAirportOrigin' entity and be able to add this to my `Origin` class:

```
public boolean IsNonAirportOrigin {get; set;}
```

So, if Origin.OriginId is in NonAirportOrigins then Origin.IsNonAirportOrigin = true.

**Can anyone show me the Migrations or Data Annotations to do this?**

Comment: There are something incoherent to your post.
You don't need to have NonAirportOrigin entity but you need to check if an Id exist into this table before setting IsNonAirportOrigin.

Comment: @CodeNotFound -  I want to treat it like you do a mapping table that sits in bettween a many to many relationship.  With a many to many table, you don't need to have the mapping table as an entity.  (Just as a table in the db).

Comment: I think, only insert trigger on table "ReferenceManual.NonAirportOrigin" will help you.